Is it possible to create a total sum as part of a large select query
I have the below query which works well but I'm just trying to also include a statement that will give me a total from column 'P' - SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT on a new row at the bottom of the output.
 select oc.card_number,
       case opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' then '05-PURCHASE' 
       when 'OPTP0020' then '06-CREDIT VOUCHER' 
       else 'other' end as Transaction_Type,
       opt.oper_date as TRANSACTION_DATE, 
       op.account_number, 
       case vf.sttl_currency
       when '840' then 'USD'
       end as SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY, 
   TO_CHAR (
      CASE opt.oper_type
         WHEN 'OPTP0000' THEN COALESCE (-vf.sttl_amount /100, 0)
         ELSE vf.sttl_amount /100
      END,
      '99G999D00') AS SOURCE_AMOUNT,
       op.auth_code, 
       opt.mcc, 
       opt.terminal_number as TERMINAL_ID, 
       vf.pos_terminal_cap, 
       vf.pos_entry_mode,
       opt.part_key as CAPTURE_DATE, 
       TO_CHAR (
       CASE opt.oper_type
       when 'OPTP0000' THEN COALESCE (-vf.oper_amount /100, 0)
       ELSE vf.oper_amount /100
       END,
       '99G999D00') as TRANSACTION_AMOUNT,
       COALESCE(ccu.name,opt.oper_currency) TRANSACTION_CURRENCY,
        case vf.sttl_currency
       when '840' then 'BMD'
       end as SETTLEMENT_CURRENCY, 
   TO_CHAR (
      CASE opt.oper_type
         WHEN 'OPTP0000' THEN COALESCE (-vf.sttl_amount /100, 0)
         ELSE vf.sttl_amount /100
      END,
      '99G999D00') AS SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,
       opt.merchant_name,
       COALESCE(cc.visa_country_code,opt.merchant_country) merchant_country,
       opt.clearing_sequence_num, 
       opt.clearing_sequence_count, 
       opt.oper_type
FROM   opr_operation opt 
       INNER JOIN opr_participant op
       ON op.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN opr_card oc
       ON oc.oper_id = opt.id
       INNER JOIN vis_fin_message vf
       ON     opt.id = vf.id
       INNER JOIN  com_country cc
       ON cc.code= opt.merchant_country 
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id
       INNER JOIN  com_currency ccu
       ON ccu.code= opt.oper_currency 
          AND op.card_id = vf.card_id   
WHERE  opt.clearing_sequence_num > 1
AND    opt.part_key >= DATE '2024-03-01'
AND    opt.msg_type IN ('MSGTPAMC', 'MSGTPACC')
AND    op.participant_type = 'PRTYISS'

OUTPUT
"CARD_NUMBER"   "TRANSACTION_TYPE"  "TRANSACTION_DATE"  "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT" "AUTH_CODE" "MCC"   "TERMINAL_ID"   "POS_TERMINAL_CAP"  "POS_ENTRY_MODE"    "CAPTURE_DATE"  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"    "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY"  "SETTLEMENT_CURRENCY"   "SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT" "MERCHANT_NAME" "MERCHANT_COUNTRY"  "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_NUM" "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_COUNT"   "OPER_TYPE"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   25-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "718515"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   25-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "718523"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   25-MAR-24   "006008007501"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "718529"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735762"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735770"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "006008007501"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735776"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "006000095511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735780"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   28-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -22.48"    "760673"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    02-APR-24   "    -20.20"    "EUR"   "BMD"   "    -22.48"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "DE"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456""06-CREDIT VOUCHER"   28-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   "     26.32"    "760660"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    02-APR-24   "     20.20"    "GBP"   "BMD"   "     26.32"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "GB"    2   2   "OPTP0020"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   28-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "760667"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    02-APR-24   "    -20.20"    "USD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "US"    2   2   "OPTP0000"

I think part of my problem is that I have a rule in place of
  TO_CHAR (
      CASE opt.oper_type
         WHEN 'OPTP0000' THEN COALESCE (-vf.sttl_amount /100, 0)
         ELSE vf.sttl_amount /100
      END,
      '99G999D00') AS SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT,

So I'm just not sure how I can bring in the total sum so that it would calculate SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT in this example of TOTAL = -157.76 underneath the last row.
"CARD_NUMBER"   "TRANSACTION_TYPE"  "TRANSACTION_DATE"  "ACCOUNT_NUMBER"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT_CURRENCY"    "SOURCE_AMOUNT" "AUTH_CODE" "MCC"   "TERMINAL_ID"   "POS_TERMINAL_CAP"  "POS_ENTRY_MODE"    "CAPTURE_DATE"  "TRANSACTION_AMOUNT"    "TRANSACTION_CURRENCY"  "SETTLEMENT_CURRENCY"   "SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT" "MERCHANT_NAME" "MERCHANT_COUNTRY"  "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_NUM" "CLEARING_SEQUENCE_COUNT"   "OPER_TYPE"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   25-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "718515"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   25-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "718523"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   25-MAR-24   "006008007501"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "718529"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    27-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735762"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735770"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "006008007501"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735776"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   26-MAR-24   "006000095511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "735780"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    28-MAR-24   "    -20.20"    "BMD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "BM"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   28-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -22.48"    "760673"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    02-APR-24   "    -20.20"    "EUR"   "BMD"   "    -22.48"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "DE"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
"1234567890123456""06-CREDIT VOUCHER"   28-MAR-24   "004000485011"  "USD"   "     26.32"    "760660"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    02-APR-24   "     20.20"    "GBP"   "BMD"   "     26.32"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "GB"    2   2   "OPTP0020"
"1234567890123456"  "05-PURCHASE"   28-MAR-24   "006000152511"  "USD"   "    -20.20"    "760667"    "5734"  "TERMID01"  "9" "01"    02-APR-24   "    -20.20"    "USD"   "BMD"   "    -20.20"    "ACQUIRER NAME            " "US"    2   2   "OPTP0000"
                                                                                                                                                                                                       TOTAL = -157.76    


Hi you can try GROUP BY ROLLUP may be this could work for you, there is another option is to have another query using Union and keep all the columns as space or null except the column where you need the sum.

I miss SQL Server's COMPUTE clause.

You can use the below where the total will be shown in the last row of the data
decode(rownum,count(1) over(),SUM(settlement_amount) OVER ()) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT

IF you are using SQLPLUS and want it in a new row try the below
   SET     FEEDBACK    OFF

   COLUMN  total_amt  NEW_VALUE  TOTAL_AMOUNT  NOPRINT

   DEFINE  TOTAL_AMOUNT  = 0

      SELECT    d.*,
      TO_CHAR (SUM (SETTLEMENT_AMOUNT) OVER ())  AS total_amt
      FROM      your_query_view  d
      ORDER BY  1;

      PROMPT  TOTAL&TOTAL_AMOUNT

You can use like the below
    select *
      from your_query
      union
            select null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   'TOTAL:',
                   SUM(settlement_amount) OVER(),
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null,
                   null
              from your_query;


Also, I forgot to add that the number of rows may increase/decrease so I cant set it to a fixed number of rows. Of the answers above, where would I insert them in to my select query?

no problem it will work irrespective of your rows count

thanks @psaraj so if  use this decode(rownum,count(1) over(),SUM(settlement_amount) OVER ()) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT, where would it go in my select query above? I have tried a few places but I can't get it to work at all

@headspace updated the answer on usage

Here are two of the options to do it...
Tested it with below sample data as a cte:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :    (this could be your query)
    some_query AS
        ( Select 1 "ID", 'Name 1' "A_NAME", DATE '2024-04-08' "A_DATE", 110 "A_NUMBER", 56 "ANOTHER_NUMBER" From Dual Union All 
          Select 2 "ID", 'Name 2' "A_NAME", DATE '2024-04-09' "A_DATE", 220 "A_NUMBER", 59 "ANOTHER_NUMBER" From Dual Union All
          Select 3 "ID", 'Name 3' "A_NAME", DATE '2024-04-10' "A_DATE", 330 "A_NUMBER", 57 "ANOTHER_NUMBER" From Dual 
        )


Using UNION ALL

Select    * 
From      some_query
UNION ALL
Select Null, 'TOTAL:', Null, Sum(A_NUMBER), Null From some_query


Using MODEL Clause

SELECT    *
FROM    ( Select    *
          From      some_query
        )
        MODEL   Dimension By (ID)
                Measures (A_NAME, A_DATE, A_NUMBER, ANOTHER_NUMBER)
        RULES (   A_NAME[null] = 'TOTAL:',
                  A_NUMBER[null] = Sum(A_NUMBER)[ID Is Not Null]
              )

... both results as:
/*
        ID A_NAME A_DATE     A_NUMBER ANOTHER_NUMBER
---------- ------ -------- ---------- --------------
         1 Name 1 08.04.24        110             56
         2 Name 2 09.04.24        220             59
         3 Name 3 10.04.24        330             57
           TOTAL:                 660                 */

